# Why is the Karaf WebConsole allowing bad values in the ConfigAdmin service?

Tags: java, configuration, osgi, apache-karaf

I have just implemented an OSGi bundle that uses the `org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService` and `org.osgi.service.metatype.MetaTypeProvider` to allow the **ConfigurationAdmin** to handle its configuration. The Bundle does some checks in the `updated(Dictionary<String, ?>)` method, for example checking that file paths are valid ect. If it finds errors it throws a `ConfigurationException`.

When i add "bad" data to the configuration, a ConfigurationException IS actually thrown, as i can see in the log, but there is no notion of the error in the **WebConsole**.

So: when i go into the Karaf WebConsole and proceed into **OSGi->Configuration**, and persist some configuration that makes the bundle throw a ConfigurationException, the WebConsole just continues as if no error happened. When i open the configuration again, the bad value is still listed in the configuration, even through it was never applied to my bundle.

Is this the intended behavior? I can't quite see the logic in saving bad data that results in a ConfigurationException.
If it is NOT intended behavior, then do you have any idea what i am doing wrong?

I am using:

```
Karaf 4.0.1
Metatype 1.0.12
ConfigAdmin 1.8.4
```

Comment: might just open an issue at the felix web-console as Karaf just uses that one.